# How to Insert special characters in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to collect news articles and store the content in a db. I need to do it quickly say 300 news articles in less than 15mins time. The news content is having lots of special characters in between like "'" etc. Is there any way to say the database to ignore those characters while writing to the database? Insert query is failing.

Thanks.

Comment: i am using C# to build the string and directly sending it to database. I am not concerned with sqlinjection etc.

Comment: can you provide that insert query what you are trying with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, i did not analyse the issue correctly, its just the quote that is effecting the query and i droped the quote instead of adding double quotes to escape as it doesn't make any difference.

if not using like then only ' will be the issue in SQL Server 2008 - point learnt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterise your INSERT statement - you'll save yourself a lot of problems like this. The other benefits of doing so include execution plan reuse (good for performance) and SQL injection protection.

Comment: Using a regular expresion to remove quotes before passing the string. For now it seems to be working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do it quickly say 300 news articles in less than 15mins time

Other people would consider your definition of quick as very slow. 300 article inserts should go in 15 seconds, not 15 minutes.

> Insert query is failing

Show the query please plus the error. if you use parameters you have no problem with that unless your data is too long to handle properly in a parameter.

Comment: The SQL Query i am trying to run from C# is - sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [StockPredictData].[dbo].[" + bomCode + "]([NewsURL],[NewsDate],[WebSiteName],[NewsTitle],[NewsShortSnippet],[NewsBody]) VALUES ('" + urlList[i] + "','" + dateList[i] + "','" + urlNameList[i] + "','" + urlTitleList[i] + "','" + shortSampleBodyList[i] + "','" + bodyList[i] + "')";
                    sqlaccessobj.ExecuteCommand(sqlconobj, sqlQuery, "write");

Comment: During debugging this is what i have